# convergence of this series with n^a*(\log(n))^b in denominator

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

How do I proceed with finding a and b such that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a {(\log(n)})^b}$ converges ? Which test is the most appropriate to use and find the values ?

Answer (score 0):

- Kindly look at [Cauchy Condenstation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).